# Does the number of returned fields affect TVFs performance?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure out do the defferent sets of requested fields from the next TVF affect the performance (does query optimazer compute all selected statements inside its body despite on how many fields you wish to retrive outside?):

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_bc_snapshot_OptionValue](
@date_min smalldatetime,
@date_max smalldatetime,
@uid int,
@isRecalc bit
)
returns table
AS
RETURN (                      
select
    convert(varchar(8), s.t_date, 112) as t_date,
    s.stock_id,
    convert(varchar(8), s.exp_date_MDB, 112) as exp_date,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,3),s.strike) as varchar) as strike,
    s.call_put,
    s.root_id,
    s.root,
    s.style,
    s.option_symbol_MDB as option_symbol,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,3),s.bid) as varchar) as bid,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,3),s.ask) as varchar) as ask,
    case when s.settlement = 0 then s.settlement else cast(convert(decimal(10,3),s.settlement) as varchar) end as settlement,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,3),s.price) as varchar) as price,
    s.open_interest,
    s.volume,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,5),s.iv) as varchar) as iv,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,5),s.delta) as varchar) as delta,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,5),s.gamma) as varchar) as gamma,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,5),s.theta) as varchar) as theta,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,5),s.vega) as varchar) as vega,
    cast(convert(decimal(18,5),s.rho) as varchar) as rho,
    cast(isnull(s.is_interpolated,0) as varchar) as is_interpolated,
    cast(isnull(s.status,0) as varchar) as status,
    s.shift,
    s.expiration_id,
    convert(varchar(8), s.calc_date, 112) as calc_date

    ,s.spc
    ,s.se_code
    ,convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(D,s.shift,s.exp_date_MDB), 112) as shifted_expiry   -- added by O.Brilkov 2019-02-06
from iv.dbo.bc_snapshot_OptionValue s
left join (select stock_id from iv.dbo.fn_BulkUser_stock(@uid)) instruments on s.stock_id = instruments.stock_id
where (s.t_date between @date_min and @date_max or s.calc_date between @date_min and @date_max)
    and s.is_recalc = case when isnull(@isRecalc,1) = 1 then s.is_recalc else 0 end
    and s.stock_id = case when @uid is null then s.stock_id else instruments.stock_id end
    --and s.t_date >= isnull((select ContractDate from iv.dbo.BulkUser where bulkUserID = @uid),s.t_date)
)
```

Here are queries I'm executing:

```
select t_date, stock_id, exp_date, strike, call_put, root_id, [root], style, option_symbol, bid, ask, settlement, price, open_interest, volume, iv, delta, gamma, theta, vega, rho, is_interpolated, [status], shift, expiration_id, calc_date, shifted_expiry
from iv.dbo.fn_bc_snapshot_OptionValue('20190205', '20190205',438,1)

select t_date, stock_id, exp_date, strike, call_put, root_id, [root], style, option_symbol, bid, ask, settlement, price, open_interest, volume, iv, delta, gamma, theta, vega, rho, is_interpolated, [status], shift, expiration_id, calc_date
from iv.dbo.fn_bc_snapshot_OptionValue('20190205', '20190205',438,1)
```

As you can see, guys, there is no "shifted_expiry" in the second query, but is it computed every time I invoke my function?

Comment: Engine is smart enough to not calculate things that won't be needed. You can see this when doing a `SELECT *` as a subquery and only referencing 1 column on the outmost `SELECT`, for example. Exceptions are when using TVF that aren't inline. Can always review the execution plan when doubting.

Comment: EzLo - thanks. The execution plan is too big so I can't even read it properly.. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @LordHolg, newer versions of SSMS have a compare execution plans feature. You can use that even against an older SQL version.

Comment: @Dan Guzman, thanks, but I don't have a chance to deploy the newer versions on our production environment, we still use pretty old 2008 R2 version :(
Nevertheless, that's good to know

Answer (score 0):

Check this example out:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestFunction ()
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    SELECT
        Constant = 'Value',
        FailedExpression = CONVERT(INT, 'Failed')
)
```

If we try to select all columns...

```
SELECT T.* FROM TestFunction() AS T

-- Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
-- Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Failed' to data type int.
```

But only the one without the problem:

```
SELECT T.Constant FROM TestFunction() AS T

-- Constant
-- Value
```

Engine is smart enough to not calculate things that won't be needed. Exceptions are when using TVF that aren't inline.

Comment: Got it, tnx again!